# cookie wiht no expiration is not deleted when the browser is restarted

Tags: javascript

I use this function to to write cookies in the client:

```
createCookie: function(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

and I set a cookie this way:

```
createCookie("foo", "1"); // no expiration time
```

I expect the browser to delete this cookie when it is shut down and in fact it works like that most of the times. I noticed though, that in firefox this is not the case and the cookie remains there even after the restart.

I guess it depends on some settings that allow the user to freeze the state of the browser at the time when it is shut so that, when re-launching it, all the tabs you were using are still there and kicking.

Anyone has ever experienced something like that?

Any workaround you can recommend??

Cheers

Comment: What is exactly the problem ?

Comment: @aurel.g A cookie without an expiration time is a session cookie, so it shouldn't be available across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to solve this problem exactly, I do have a suggestion that should work, with one caveat; it will constrain your session not only to a browser session, but to a specific tab.

What you could do is set the `window.name` to a random number and then append that identifier to the cookie names for that session.  When reading cookies, only use cookies whose identifier matches the one in the name of the window.  `window.name` was chosen because it persists across refreshes and navigation.

Not the greatest solution, but it will counteract the issue you're seeing.

Additionally, if you need to store more than just that identifier in the window.name, you can json_encode and then base64_encode an object to store more properties.